# Numeric range with regular expression

Tags: regex, range

I need a regular expression to find a number in the range [40010-40100]. I tried with this `40[0-1][0-9][0-9]` but it doesn't work. Could someone help me?

Comment: This is not a good use of regular expressions. What scripting language are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression: Numeric range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377926/regular-expression-numeric-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

`40(0([1-9][0-9])|100)`

Answer (score 5):

This should do : `(40100|400[1-9][0-9])`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
40((0[1-9][0-9])|(100))
```

Although this is not a great task for a regular expression.  It would be much easier to simply do a range comparison on the number

Answer (score 1):

`/400[1-9][0-9]|40100/`

Why oh why can't I just post the answer without an "Oops!"?