# Regex for two years separated by a forward slash

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to learning Regex and I am struggling with this basic issue. I want to make sure a string is in a format like: 2000/2001 or 2010/2011.

I tried something like: ^[2000-2900]./.[2000-2900]$ but I know this is wrong!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You're struggling - What have you tried? What platform are you using? Did you forgot to escape the slash?

Comment: You must tag the programming language you're using, otherwise there's no way of telling what regex patterns will work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression: Numeric range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377926/regular-expression-numeric-range); read http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: If you're going to build a regular expression you should be using a test-driven approach, define a set of input values that should pass, and, more importantly, a set of input values that should fail.

Comment: Btw, here's a good tool for learning regex: http://regexpal.com/ (check out the quick reference menu on top right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be the very basic:

```
^\d{4}\/\d{4}$
```

From the beginning of the string, check if it has 4 digits followed by  a "/" (escaped with "\") and another 4 digits to the end of the string.

Comment: This might be valid, but there's no way of telling unless OP provides more data. `0000/0000` would be matched, but might not be valid.

Comment: Yeah the OP asked for a format regex.

Comment: Yes, but you can see the provided example shows a tendency toward numbers in the range of `2000-2900`.

Answer (score 1):

If you searching for where the entire string must match then:

```
^\d{4}/\d{4}$
```

If you are searching for a sub string of a larger string then:

```
\d{4}/\d{4}
```

And if you using in C# then remember to wrap it up in a verbatim string like so:

```
@"^\d{4}/\d{4}$"
@"\d{4}/\d{4}"
```

I noticed that others are escaping the forward slash but I don't think is necessary but doesn't do any harm if you do.