# Python regex equivalent of bash's {1..4}

Tags: python, regex, bash

Does python's regular expression have anything equivalent to match numbers in a given range?

For example in bash, you can match test19.txt, test20.txt, test21.txt by test{19..21}.txt

I am **not** looking for regular expression to match all digits like [1-2][0-9].

I want to match only a particular series of numbers starting from some number to another.

Update: The final aim is to create a regexp object with re.compile(), so that i can use it to search a big list of strings.

Comment: Note that what you show isn't a regex, but a shell expansion. Bash doesn't do regexes.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks, True. I was looking for the regexp substitute for shell expansion.

Comment: @Marcin Bash does do regex, both for glob expansion (with extglob) and through  `=~`. This -- brace expansion -- however, doesn't match anything. It merely iterates string combination.

Comment: `extglob` does not use regexes, but so-called extended patterns. They provide some, but not all, of the functionality that regexes have compared to basic patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
['text' + str(i) + '.txt' for i in range(19, 22)]
```

Will give you that list:

```
['test19.txt', 'test20.txt', 'test21.txt']
```

So you can list of the files that are in that list. For example if you have a list of words named `words` and want to filter those that match it:

```
r = ['text' + str(i) + '.txt' for i in range(19, 22)]
[x for x in words if x in r]
```

But if you really want a regexp:

```
re.compile('|'.join(['text' + str(i) + '.txt' for i in range(19, 22)]))
```

Comment: Actually, i wanted to generate a regular expression to match them. something like re.compile('the regexp magic'). So that i can use it for matching in a huge list of strings.

Comment: You can surely construct your regexp using the trick I gave and a regexp or. If you only have a list of strings and want to filter those that match `test{19..21}.txt`, then use `in ['text' + str(i) + '.txt' for i in range(19, 22)]` in a for loop or list-comprehension.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes, I think i shall use the method you suggested to generate a list of regexps and use | to combine.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is another similar question ([Regular Expression: Numeric Range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1377926/2375855)), whose answers recommend to use regular expressions only to match for the occurrence of a number using something along the lines of `\d{1,3}`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235523/2375855) points to the command line tool [`rgxg`](http://rgxg.sourceforge.net/) which can generate regular expressions that match a specified number range.

Comment: Thanks. rgxg looks very nice. but i was thinking of using only standard python.

Comment: Maybe you can use the code that forms this feature from the C source code and to implement it in a (I would assume quite) short Python function?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have these files:

```
$ cd test
$ touch file{1..25}.txt
$ ls
file1.txt   file14.txt  file19.txt  file23.txt  file5.txt
file10.txt  file15.txt  file2.txt   file24.txt  file6.txt
file11.txt  file16.txt  file20.txt  file25.txt  file7.txt
file12.txt  file17.txt  file21.txt  file3.txt   file8.txt
file13.txt  file18.txt  file22.txt  file4.txt   file9.txt
```

You can use glob to match the grand pattern of `file[numers].txt`:

```
import glob
import os
import re

os.chdir('/Users/andrew/test')

print glob.glob('file[0-9]*.txt')
# ['file1.txt', 'file10.txt', 'file11.txt', 'file12.txt', 'file13.txt', 'file14.txt', 'file15.txt', 'file16.txt', 'file17.txt', 'file18.txt', 'file19.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file20.txt', 'file21.txt', 'file22.txt', 'file23.txt', 'file24.txt', 'file25.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt', 'file5.txt', 'file6.txt', 'file7.txt', 'file8.txt', 'file9.txt']
```

Then use a list comprehension with regex to narrow that list:

```
def expand(x,lo=0,hi=sys.maxint): 
    return lo<=int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group(0))<=hi

print [e for e in glob.glob('file[0-9]*.txt') if expand(e, 8,12)]
# ['file10.txt', 'file11.txt', 'file12.txt', 'file8.txt', 'file9.txt']
```

Or use filter:

```
print filter(lambda x: expand(x, 9, 12), glob.glob('file[0-9]*.txt'))
# ['file10.txt', 'file11.txt', 'file12.txt', 'file9.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you looking for?

there is always `range(19,22)` which is depending on what you are looking close to curly expansion