# How can I make this date regex more strict?

Tags: regex, date

I want to validate a string to see if it is a valid date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.  I'm not very good with regex, but I've managed to get it to validate strings with four 0-9 characters in the beginning followed by the hyphen, followed by two 0-9 chars, another hyphen, and two more 0-9 chars in the end.  How could I make this regex match dates with only 1-12 in the month and 1-31 in the day?

Here's what I have so far:

```
([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})
```

Comment: Leading zeros required?

Comment: Yes. The leading zeros are required.

Comment: Related: [Regular Expression: Numeric range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377926/regular-expression-numeric-range)

Comment: FYI I've tested all three answers, the regexes are different but they all work. :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

```
$pattern = '~\A(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\z~';

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $m) && checkdate($m[2], $m[3], $m[1])) {
    // TRUE
} else {
    // FALSE
}
```

The advantage is that `checkdate` checks if the date exists *(including cases of leap years)*. With this approach, there's no need to delegate more tasks to the regex part.

Answer (score 0):

### Anchors First

The most important thing in this validation is that you use the `^` and `$` anchors to prevent a substring from matching in the middle of your input.

As for the regex, this is what I would suggest (assuming years start with a `1` or `2`)

```
^([12][0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([012][1-9]|[123]0|31)$
```

This [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/2) tests the day part of the regex, while [this other demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/3) tests the month part.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- For the year, `[12][0-9]{3}` matches a 1 or 2 followed by three digits
- For the month, `(0[1-9]|1[012]` matches `0` then 1 through 9, or `1` then 0, 1 or 2
- For the day, `[012][1-9]|[123]0|31` matches a 0, 1 or 2 followed by a digit from 1 to 9, or 1, 2 or 3 followed by a `0`, or `31`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: FYI: after tweaking added a [demo to test the month](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/3) part of the regex, and a [demo to test the day](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/4).