# Regex for human temperature range?

Tags: regex

What is the regex for any number, float or int, within range of 95 to 106?

- `95` to `106` are acceptable values
- `95.0` and `106.0` are valid inputs along with all floats within range
- `95` and `106.0` are also valid inputs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression: Numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377926/regular-expression-numeric-range)

Comment: Regular Expressions aren't the right tool for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1377937/1247512 answers a similar question thoughtfully.

Comment: @rebusB, allowing floats as well as integers complicates things, depending on the amount of verification desired (rejecting `101.1.3`, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that temperatures are representations of integers or floats having a digit after the decimal point, you could use the following regular expression.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7F0AT/6/)

The regex engine engine performs the following operations.

```
\b             match a word break
(?<!\.)        the following character is not preceded by '.'
(?:            begin a non-capture group
  (?:          begin a non-capture group
    9[5-9]     match '9' followed by '5', '6', '7', '8' or '9'
    |          or
    10[0-5]    match '10' followed by '0', '1', '2', '3', '4' or '5'
  )            end a non-capture group
  (?:\.\d)?    optionally match a decimal and one digit
  |            or
  106          match '106'
  (\.0)?       optionally match '.0'
)              end non-capture group
(?!\.)         the previous character is not to be followed by '.'
\b             match a word break
```